# Android Architechture Navigation - onSupportNavigateUp()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

While using Navigation Library, is it okay to finish the inner activity with `finish()` in `onSupportNavigateUp()`? Or we should use `NavController` to remove that `Activity` from Stack? And, I have trouble using NavController to remove `Activity`.

My Navigation graph looks like below:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/home_frag">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_frag"
        android:name="com.yamikrish.app.slicedemo.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="home_frag"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/open_details"
            app:destination="@id/details_fragment" />

    </fragment>

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
        android:name="com.yamikrish.app.slicedemo.ui.detail.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/post_detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/detail_page">

        <argument
            android:name="id"
            app:type="integer" />

    </activity>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_frag"
        android:name="com.yamikrish.app.slicedemo.ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/profile_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

I have tried to use like below:

**(i) Using NavController inside DetailActivity**

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val nav = NavController(this)
        return  nav.navigateUp()
}
```

But getting exception as,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NavController back stack is empty

**(ii) Using NavController inside BaseActivity**

```
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
            return  findNavController(R.id.container).navigateUp()
    }
```

That also not working. Am I doing it wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Your detail activity has no concept of the parent nav graph in this case. You example **ii** is correct. Since BaseActivity contains a navigation graph. I don't know what the DetailActivity is doing but if it also contains a navigation graph then you should use the same code as your BaseActivity. The fact that you're getting that error and also creating a new NavController on the fly tells me that DetailActivity is not using a navigation graph (creating a new NavController and not providing it with a graph will by default initialize with an empty back stack).

In summary, DetailActivity's onSupportNavigateUp should behave like a normal up navigation. If there's a clear parent you should launch it, otherwise, just finish().